# CSS classes with dyanamic vs statically loaded pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a web application right now that is going to need to perform a lot of drawing and a lot of client side operations. I'm using inline SVG within 'div' elements that have certain CSS classes and style attributes.  When I load these divs in a static page, they load fine, everything runs as expected.  However, when I parse these from a string with jQuery and add them to the DOM, they don't.  It's like the CSS classes get completely ignored.

When I inspect the elements in the different cases in Firebug, I get an unexpected result: the statically added element has the expected class name: 'class1 class2 class3', as does the dynamically generated element. However, the statically generated element also has a 'classList' property which is an array with 3 elements: 'class1', 'class2' and 'class3'.  For the dynamically generated element, this attribute is null.  The statically generated element works fine with CSS (gets all my hovers, draggable, etc) whereas the dynamically generated element looks like it's not even getting CSS applied to it at all.  Can somebody please explain what 'classList' is, why it exists, and why this difference between the elements exists ?

Comment: classList is a convenience attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.classList

Comment: anyway you could post an example of jQuery dynamic code you're seeing this happen on?

Comment: A jsfiddle.net demo would be great.

Comment: also, if you use "div.classList.add("someclass");", it should add a class successfully to that div.  Are the div's also dynamically generated or can you keep the divs statically on the page as placeholders that you then use the "add" routine with?

Comment: Did you ever sort this out Alex? I have a similar problem. If I copy the html from the inspector for the svg generated by js, and paste it into the page, the class is recgnised and styles applied perfectly but the dynamic one is ignored. The inspector shows identical markup for both. It seems like a bug but happens across browsers. Did you make any progress? I have a work-around (build a div container in js and add the svg markup as text, including class attribute, inside it before appending the div element to page) but its odd that an svg element fails (and it's unrelated to svg namespace)

Answer (score 0):

The classList is simply a convenience API to access the classes of an element. See [enter link description here](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/01/classlist-in-firefox-3-6/).

However, I have no clue, why your dynamic content does have a null value here, but a correct className entry.